# How can I guarantee something is rendered with what's in state, but then clear state so it's not there next time?

Tags: reactjs

So we have a component that has an error boundary that we wrap around our entire app.  We use it to catch any unhandled exceptions and display a friendly error page.

The problem is when it catches an error it stores the error in state and then it get's stuck in state.  So you can imagine something like

```
<ErrorBoundary><App><Routes>...</Routes></App></ErrorBoundary>
```

Now, once an error happens they can't get out of the error boundary, they can't click on any Nav Links etc, it will always show the error boundary.

And if we clear the error once in ErrorBoundary we don't see the error at all...  It triggers a rerender with no error before being output to the browser..

So I noticed that "render" has a callback.  I was wondering, is there anyway I can basically get a callback when a render happens that has a global error in state?  Then can I use that call back to basically reset the state of the entire app to it's initial state so that when they click on a nav link it's with fresh state?

Comment: I think you should wrap ErrorBoundary inside App, something like this `<App><ErrorBoundary><Routes>...</Routes></ErrorBoundary></App>`. Then you could have App's state and setState function to control setting and clear the error. Your error state and clear function could be access everywhere in the app by passing in props, or use some else like redux, than you have full control on it.

Comment: We are using MobX and have a global store and the error is in the store.  But if we clear the error in the store, the observer fires and rerenders the error component and you can't see the error.

So I need to guarantee the error get's seen and then clear it without causing a rerender.  So maybe a use case for a reducer?

Comment: sound like to me you want to prompt the error and to ensure it won't be prompt again. You currently using the error message to indicate to prompt the error or not. My thought is saving the error message and "show the prompt indicator" separately. Then you can control to only show the error message once without clearing the error message.